# Adding a horizontal line to a D3.js barplot function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I am creating a leaflet map with popup d3 barplots that are tied to specific geographic points. I am using this code to create the leaflet popups (but with my own data): http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/11602fac1ea66c2a6d7f78067b2deddb

I want to be able to add a fixed horizontal line (which will represent a threshold in that data), something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHlwI.png). I added a fixed line to the code (after [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705279/how-to-add-a-line-on-x-axis-on-a-horizontal-bar-chart-in-d3)):

```
var lineEnd = 90;

var line = svg.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y1", function(){ return y(lineEnd)})
    .attr("y2", function(){ return y(lineEnd)})
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("stroke", "black");
```

But in the output on my leaflet map, the line seems [to appear at arbitrary points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB4d5.png) on the graphs. Does anyone have any ideas of what I might need to change in [the original code](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/11602fac1ea66c2a6d7f78067b2deddb) to be able to add this horizontal line?

Comment: @mgraham Thank you! Yes, that was what I was doing wrong. I changed the code I posted above to append to the g element ( var line = g.append("line") ) and now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that you add your line to the svg directly

But the bars are added to a group element that is translated

```
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+[margin.left,margin.top]+")");
```

What if you add the line to that group element instead, does it appear in the right place?